# Is it possible to pipe to console.log?

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to learn node.js.

I am trying to understand streams and piping.

Is it possible to pipe the response of http request to console.log?

I know how to do this by binding a handler to the data event but I am more interested in streaming it to the console.

```
http.get(url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(console.log);
  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log('finished');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`console.log` is just a function that pipes the process stream to an output.

*Note that the following is example code*

```
console.log = function(d) {
  process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

Piping to [process.stdout](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) does exactly the same thing.

```
http.get(url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(process.stdout);
  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log('finished');
  });
});
```

Note you can also do

```
process.stdout.write(response);
```

Comment: FWIW, process.stdout is a writable stream and as such does not emit 'end' Moreover, because of its special status it does not emit 'finish' eitgher.

Comment: This doesn't work for me 
```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object```

Comment: @Tyguy7 What? First off that's throwing from inside a promise that you aren't catching, and read the error message. You're passing an object, not a stream or buffer.

Comment: I realize now that the response object I was trying to pipe to stdout was actually a response object from using request.js, not http.

Comment: I get the same (internal) error Tyguy got, also mentioned [in this GH issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19399), where if I `pipe` to stdout, it throws, but if I `.on("data", console.log)` it works exactly as expected.  So, that's one case where this answer is incorrect, I think because console.log does some additional processing on non-string inputs.